# $R$-algebras and the tensor-algebra.

Tags: modules

In D & F, theorem $31(2)$ on page $442$, in the proof of the theorem given below (assuming that $M$ is an $R$-module over a commutative ring $R$ with $1$)

> If $A$ is any $R$-algebra and $\varphi:M \to A$ is an R-module
> homomorphism, then there is a unique R-algebra homomorphism $\phi:\mathcal{T}(M) \to A$ such that $\phi|_{M} = \varphi$

they start by saying: "To prove $(2)$, assume that $\varphi:M \to A$ is an $R$-algebra homomorphism."

But why should we assume this? Does not this require $M$ to be an $R$-algebra? $M$ is by assumption just an $R$-module. This is perhaps a naive question, but I don´t understand what motivates this assumption.

Comment: Continue reading the proof, and I believe you will find the assumption is not used. Indeed, I believe it is a benign error.

Comment: This error is recorded in the errata compilation at https://math.hawaii.edu/~ralph/Classes/611/errata_3rd_edition.pdf.